# Edit a filter with a simple checkbox

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I would like to make an option for showing inactive users by checking a button.

Here is the `users` array:

```
$scope.users = [
    {firstname: 'Paul', inactive: true},
    {firstname: 'Mark', inactive: false},
    {firstname: 'Maggie', inactive: false},                   
    {firstname: 'Lucy', inactive: true}
];
```

And the table to display it:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: ??">
            <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.inactive}}</td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" ng-click="showInact()">Show inactives
```

I'm learning AngularJS, I didn't found an interesting way to do that. Can you help me finding a solution?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular checkbox filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370933/angular-checkbox-filtering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this way:

**1) At you controller:**

```
$scope.showInactive = false;

$scope.filterInact = function(item)
{
    return item.inactive === $scope.showInactive;
};

$scope.showInact = function() {
   $scope.showInactive = !$scope.showInactive;
}
```

**2) Setup the filter:**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filterInact">
    <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{user.inactive}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps me. I improved a bit your solution, be removing the function `filterInact()` and setting the filter to `filter:showInactive`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Way !! You can set value of filter on click event.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filters">
    <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{user.inactive}}</td>
</tr>
```

on click filter set to check box

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="filters.inactive = true">
```

First, You need to set controller name instade of "myCtrl.js" whatever your controller name.

Comment: It is not really effective : If you ckeck the input it applies the filter correctly, but it doesn't undo if you click again

Comment: Then you need to uncheck this one and add new checkbox for inactive = false. it's just easiest way. not effective!!

Answer (score 0):

I personally like using a filter function to filter data.  This approach is flexible and can easily interact with your other form variables.  From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), the filter expression can be a:

> `function(value, index)`: A predicate function can be used to write
>   arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of array.
>   The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate
>   returned true for.

So an example filter function might look like this:

```
$scope.filterFunc = function (user) {
  //if the checkbox is checked show everyone, else only those that aren't inactive
  return $scope.showInactives  || !user.inactive;
};
```

And the HTML would be changed to accommodate the filter function.  Specifically, I'm binding the checkbox to a `$scope` variable (`$scope.showInactives`) that the `filterFunc` function uses in its logic.  And of course the `ng-repeat` is using the function called `filterFunc`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showInactives"/>Show inactive users
<br/>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filterFunc">
        <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{user.inactive}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And if you need any other convoluted logic, the filter function allows you a lot of freedom.  The only thing it needs to return is a boolean (true or false).

[Demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/iONrVZf4RBC1QQz0nbXM)

Unrelated to filtering, I also had to fix the table's HTML by putting the `<th>` inside a table row `<tr>`.